# Checking `c_associated` on a `nullptr` causes segfault unless pointer has `value` attribute

Tags: c++, pointers, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

In short: I have a fortran subroutine that accepts a `c_ptr`, and checks if it is `null` by using `c_associated`. Unless I give the pointer the `VALUE` attribute, the check triggers a segfault.

I have found a way to work around this, but I am interested in what is causing this behaviour. To me it smells like it has something to do with Fortran implicitly passing by reference. With my main library (not shown) this behaviour only shows up when I compile with optimizations (not when using `-O0 -g`), but I have not been able to create a minimal example reproducing that behaviour.

Example:

In main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
void test_ptr(double* ptr);
}

int main(){
  
  double* ptr{nullptr};

  std::cout << "In C++, pointer is " << ptr << std::endl;
  test_ptr(ptr);
  std::cout << "Fortran exited without fault." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In `test.f90`

```
module test
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
public test_ptr

contains

subroutine test_ptr(ptr) BIND(C)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    type(c_ptr), target, intent(in) :: ptr

    print*, "In Fortran, pointer is", ptr

    if (c_associated(ptr)) then
        print*, 'Pointer is not null'
    else
        print*, 'Pointer is null'
    endif

end subroutine test_ptr

end module test
```

If I compile and link this with

```
gfortran -c test.f90 test.o -O3
g++ -c main.cpp main.o -O3
g++ -o main main.o test.o -lgfortran
```

running `./main` gives

```
In C++, pointer is 0
 In Fortran, pointer is                    0
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I have found two ways of fixing this:

*Either* by declaring `ptr` as

```
type(c_ptr), target, intent(in), value :: ptr
```

*or* by changing the C++-side to pass `&ptr`, as.

```
extern "C" {
void test_ptr(double** ptr);
}

int main(){
  
  double* ptr = nullptr;

  std::cout << "In C++, pointer is " << ptr << std::endl;
  test_ptr(&ptr);
  std::cout << "Fortran exited without fault." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Both these changes (individually) lead to the expected output

```
In C++, pointer is 0
 In Fortran, pointer is                    0
 Pointer is null
Fortran exited without fault.
```

To me it almost seems like `c_associated` is at some point trying to dereference `ptr`, without first checking if it is `null`, is this expected behaviour? Is there another (preferred) way of checking if a `c_ptr` is `null`?

Comment: In `print*, "In Fortran, pointer is", ptr` you dereference the pointer unconditionally: what do you expect to happen when that is null?

Comment: If you do not give the function parameter the `value` attribute, which indicates pass-by-value semantics, then *every* access to `ptr` will attempt to dereference the passed value as a pointer.

Comment: @francescalus That actually surprised me a bit: Even when I pass a `nullptr`, the `print*, ptr` statement just prints `0` (as posted). I assumed that meant that printing the pointer behaves as in C, that you get the address it points to without dereferencing it. Is that not the case?

Comment: `print *, ptr` probably isn't doing what you think it is doing. (It's also not allowed under the Fortran standard.) As you seem happy with the answer you have, I needn't go into more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` attribute is a Fortran 2003 feature (some compiler support it prior to that as extension). Without it it assumes that a pointer `ptr` is *passed by address* (in C), constness defined by  `intent(in)` notwithstanding, which would be an equivalent of reference to a pointer in C++. And you supplied a null pointer as that address while Fortran would dereference it implicitly on any use, e.g. `ptr = something` is equivalent of C code `*ptr = something`.

The `void test_ptr(double** ptr);` would be the correct equivalent signature for  function without `value` attribute.

PS. If you're using a legacy Fortran 90 compiler, there might be some quirks or different behaviour that do not match modern standard behavior, as `value` wasn't in standard

Comment: The code would not compile with such a legacy compiler. It uses much more than just `value` from F2003.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I think Lahey Fortran from 2002 would compile that. PortlandGroup one? Not sure. They supported everything else here, then though they formally were F90 with extensions to F95. THe kind types were there already, though their interpretation of kind  could be different ( some corporate compilers simply did  `real(4)` === `real*4`).

Comment: I doubt they had the iso_c_binding module or bind(C) before the standard became published.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава that's GNU fortran extension from around 2000. Lahey fully supported GNU

Comment: Thank you! So this is simply  Fortran treating `type(c_ptr), target, intent(in) :: ptr` as the equivalent to C's `double** ptr`, and `type(c_ptr), target, intent(in), value :: ptr` as C's `double* ptr`? Do you have any recommendation regarding best practice for passing pointers (that can be `nullptr`) between C and fortran? I'm Using gfortran 12.2.0 (from homebrew for mac with arm64), which i guess should be quite up to date.

Comment: @VegardGjeldvikJervell I didn't do anything with fortran in quite a while. Personally I'd prefer to use C-level wrappers (possibly upgraded to OOP and inlined in C++) around other language's functions, simply to localize access point. That would also allow creation of debugging checks and shortcircuits.